# get user profile in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

hello i'm new in python and django
I need a view that get current user profile I know I shoud use get_profile from User but I don't know how to use it . i read the django document and It didn't help me.
this is what I found from doc:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
profile=request.user.get_profile()
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Django's documentation says it all, specifically the part [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). First you need to define a model somewhere in your `models.py` with fields for the additional information of the user:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Other fields here
    accepted_eula = models.BooleanField()
    favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Dragons.")
```

Then, you need to indicate that this model (`UserProfile`) is the user profile by setting `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` inside your `settings.py`:

**settings.py**

```
...
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'
...
```

You need to replace `accounts` with the name of your app. Finally, you want to create a profile every time a `User` instance is created by registering a `post_save` handler, this way every time you create a user Django will create his profile too:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Other fields here
    accepted_eula = models.BooleanField()
    favorite_animal = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Dragons.")


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

#### Accessing the Profile

To access the current user's profile in your view, just use the `User` instance provided by the request, and call [get_profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile) on it:

```
def your_view(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    ...
    # Your code
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer but my broblem is in the view part .. I already have my model and I don't know how to use my model detail in view

Comment: @nim4n inside your views you already have the User inside the request. So, to get the profile you just need to do: profile = request.user.get_profile()

Comment: does it work on 1.5? It seems that since 1.5 there is no auth_profile, but auth_model

Comment: @ПавелТявин AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is not supported in Django 1.5

Comment: last night I tried so many time and I get some error. today I runserver to write the error here but It works fine!! I didn't change anything from last night :)

Comment: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE and get_profile() are deprecated. Please add that to your answer

Answer (score 6):

Basically django User models will provide access only for the fields ( firstname,lastname,email,password,is_staff,is_active,last_login).

However if we want to add any extra fields to this model, say we need to add a new column named dateofbirth for every user, then we need to add a column named DOB into User model. But this is not possible as we aren't able to edit django User models.

To achieve this either

1.We can have a separate new table with email id & DOB column, such that a column in User model is mapped with a column in the new table. But this will create a new db instance for every db request. Say if u want to find the DOB of a customer,

- First we need to fetch the value of mapped id of a customer from the
  User table.
- WIth the above value, get DOB from the new table.

In the second method,

Instead of using django User model, use your own customize model with all the fields needed. However if any updation related to security or some enhancement made to django User model we can't use it directly. We need to do more code changes at our end( wherever we use our customize models.) This will be a bit pain for a developer to identify the code & make changes.

To overcome the above issues, django introduce django profile which is very simple and more flexible. The advantages are

- Updation/enhancement to the User model can be applied without modifying the code much
- No need of creating new db instance to fetch the extra values.
- Since the field has onetoone mapping deletion of data from one table will delete others also.
- More secure, since we use django models ( no sql injection)

How to Use this:

In settings.py create a variable AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = **"appname.profiletable"**

- In models.py, create a new table with the fields needed and make sure that the id in User model is onetoone mapped with new table.
- create a signal which inserts a row into the new table whenever a new entry is added into User model.
- The value in the new table can be accessed using User object itself.

Say, we created a new table extrauser which has DOB, emailid. To find the DOB of a customer, use

```
a=User.objects.get(email='x@x.xom')
a.get_profile().DOB will give the dateofbirth value from extrauser table.
```

Hope the above details make you clear in understanding django profile. Incase of any help further, let me know. I have used django profile in my project.

Comment: Tnx for detail. I created my user profile and I use admin interface for manage that but I need to get current user profile in my view and I have no idea how to do It

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which class is your "Profile" by setting `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'` (for example)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/

Comment: Could you please check this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806683/create-row-of-date-while-creating-superuser and guide me how to implement this.

Comment: In the question you referenced, the User doesn't have a "location" attribute because Location has a ForeignKey to User. So, an instance of User would have a "location_set" attribute.

Comment: I tried with OneToOneField,that time i got this issue"setting.models.DoesNotExist: Location matching query does not exist.
" in console while creating superuser.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some code :) Post a question with some sample code so I and others can get a better sense of what's going on.

Comment: I updated the tried code and traceback in the question,please check.

Comment: An instance of User will not have a location property that points to a Location model. It will have a `location_set` property, which contains one or more Location instances.