# Django 1.6 - showProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I'm trying to display the user profile but I keep getting this error? I'm suspecting something is wrong in the urls/views. I've tried following this [get user profile in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460426/get-user-profile-in-django)

Here is my my models.py

```
class DoctorSeeker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.name, self.email)

def create_seeker_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        DoctorSeeker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_seeker_profile, sender=User)
```

views.py

```
def showProfile(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return render(request,'/profile.html')
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^profile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showProfile, name='showProfile'),
```

This is where I'm trying to access it through in my header

```
<li><a href="/profile/{{user.id}}">My Profile</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urls, you define `id`, and pass it to the view handler `showProfile`, but the view handler signature is wrong.

Change the view handler, add argument `id` to it, after request:

```
def showProfile(request, id):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    return render(request,'/profile.html')
```