# Get a related profile via request.user in django 1.8+

Tags: python, django, django-users

I have a Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="profile_user")
    preferred_name = models.CharField()
    # more profile fields
```

that I want to access in a template via the user: `{{request.user}}`

However [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460426/get-user-profile-in-django) to this question use a method that was [removed in 1.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/)7:

> "These features have reached the end of their deprecation cycle and so have been removed in Django 1.7:
>
> - The AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting, and the get_profile() method on the User."

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) now say I should just do this, but it doesn't return anything:

`{{request.user.profile.profile_field_i_want}}`

the only difference I can see between the example and my profile model is that I use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` but the example uses `User` as the OneToOne.

However if I: `print(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)` the result is `auth.User`

I also confirmed that the users actually have profiles.

How do I access a user's related profile via request.user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access user profile from `User` model, you need to use `related_name` that was passed as argument in `OneToOneField` inside `Profile` model.

So to call `preferred_name` you need to do:

```
{{ request.user.profile_user.preferred_name }}
```

because you've provided 'profile_user' as `related_name`

Answer (score 3):

Your related_name is "profile_user", do you should use that.

```
{{request.user.profile_user.profile_field_i_want}}
```

I must say, though, I don't know why you've set that attribute: the default value of *profile" makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the critique.  I didn't realize what that was for and it must have been vestigial from following a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can just relate your profile name's id (the model class) with the User model's id like this:

```
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)  
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user).get()  
    instance = profile
```

Then call the profile attributes as so:

```
    {{ profile.phone_number }}
```